# Custom React Native component doesn't animate

Tags: react-native

So I've created a custom component in React Native, which just wraps a `TouchableOpacity` and turns it into a nice button component. Though when I use an animated version of the component (through `createAnimatedComponent`) it does not move, anyone know why?

```
const AnimatedMainButton = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(MainButton);

...

render() {
    return <AnimatedMainButton style={{transform: [{translateX: 100}]}} />
}

...

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

export default class MainButton extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        onPress: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        color: React.PropTypes.string,
        textColor: React.PropTypes.string,
    };
    static defaultProps = {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        textColor: '#000000',
    };
    render() {
        const { title, onPress, color, textColor } = this.props;

        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.mainbutton, {backgroundColor: color}]} onPress={onPress}>
                <Text style={[styles.mainbuttontext, {color: textColor}]}>{title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainbutton: {
        width: '80%',
        height: 60,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 10,
        shadowColor: '#000000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 10 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.8,
        shadowRadius: 20,
        elevation: 5,
    },
    mainbuttontext: {
        fontSize: 40,
        fontFamily: 'DroidSerif',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass down the style to the elements contained within the custom component. **duh!** Otherwise any transformations done by `AnimatedComponent`, or parents of, won't reach the native base components.

```
return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[this.props.style, ...
```